# Sorting object in JS by one of the keys in each element

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an **object** in JS structured as follows:

```
[{
    "x": 2.31,
    "y": 0.538
}, 
{
    "x": 7.07,
    "y": 0.469
}, 
{
    "x": 6.02,
    "y": 0.469
}, 
{
    "x": 2.18,
    "y": 0.458
}]
```

I need to **sort by one of the keys** in each element (sort by x). The result would look like this:

```
[{
    "x": 2.18,
    "y": 0.458
}, 
{
    "x": 2.31,
    "y": 0.538
}, 
{
    "x": 6.02,
    "y": 0.469
}, 
{
    "x": 7.07,
    "y": 0.469
}]
```

The following approach doesn't work with the above structure:

```
var sorted = [];
for(var key in dict) {
    sorted[sorted.length] = key;
}
sorted.sort();
```

Nor does the following:

```
function sortObject(o) {
    return Object.keys(o).sort().reduce((r, k) => (r[k] = o[k], r), {});
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array of objects by string property value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript)

Comment: Or this one: [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: That was it...apologies. Your first link. Didn't see it in my search. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a custom sort method.

```js
var arr = [{ "x": 2.31, "y": 0.538 }, { "x": 7.07, "y": 0.469 }, { "x": 6.02, "y": 0.469 }, { "x": 2.18, "y": 0.458 }]
arr.sort((a,b) => a.x - b.x)
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have do here is implement a custom sort method for comparison between the elements in your array.

Try this out.

```
const array = [{
    "x": 2.31,
    "y": 0.538
}, 
{
    "x": 7.07,
    "y": 0.469
}, 
{
    "x": 6.02,
    "y": 0.469
}, 
{
    "x": 2.18,
    "y": 0.458
}];

array.sort((obj1, obj2) => {
   return obj1.x - obj2.x;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can sort the key value of the object by comparing the key's value using [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

```js
var coordinates=[{
    "x": 2.31,
    "y": 0.538
}, 
{
    "x": 7.07,
    "y": 0.469
}, 
{
    "x": 6.02,
    "y": 0.469
}, 
{
    "x": 2.18,
    "y": 0.458
}]

var sortedKey=coordinates.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseFloat(a.x) - parseFloat(b.x);
});
console.log(sortedKey);
```

Comment: The values are already numbers sow by should it be relevant for this example to use `parseFloat`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortBy

> *lodash* is a modern JavaScript utility library delivering modularity, performance & extras.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/e2ccmbhh

```
let arr = [{
  "x": 2.31,
  "y": 0.538
}, 
{
  "x": 7.07,
  "y": 0.469
}, 
{
  "x": 6.02,
  "y": 0.469
}, 
{
  "x": 2.18,
  "y": 0.458
}]

let sortedArr = _.sortBy(arr, 'x');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript builtin sort() method to do that.

```
var myList = [{
            "x": 2.31,
            "y": 0.538
        },
        {
            "x": 7.07,
            "y": 0.469
        },
        {
            "x": 6.02,
            "y": 0.469
        },
        {
            "x": 2.18,
            "y": 0.458
        }];

    var sortedList = myList.sort(function(a, b){
        return a.x - b.x;
    });

    console.log(sortedList);
```